# Изображение не прикрепляется к записи WordPress

Tags: wordpress, импорт

При стандартном импорте данных  с сайта `localhost` на сервер не прикрепляется изображение к галереи `_wp_attached_file`.

Локальный домен: 
`localhost` -> `http://sites.kz`

Изображения вручную закидываю в папку `uplodas`, а потом делаю импорт.

Что может быть?  Что можно попробовать?

```
<wp:postmeta>
    <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_wp_attached_file]]></wp:meta_key>
    <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[2017/12/13100-5.jpg]]></wp:meta_value>
</wp:postmeta>
```

Пустой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То что должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код с импортируемого файла:

```
<item>
    <title>1</title>
    <link>http://sites.kz/tovar/alunna/attachment/1/</link>
    <pubDate>Sun, 03 Dec 2017 12:03:33 +0000</pubDate>
    <dc:creator><![CDATA[DaivaM]]></dc:creator>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">http://sites.kz/tovar/alunna/attachment/1/</guid>
    <description></description>
    <content:encoded><![CDATA[]]></content:encoded>
    <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[]]></excerpt:encoded>
    <wp:post_id>13245</wp:post_id>
    <wp:post_date><![CDATA[2017-12-03 15:03:33]]></wp:post_date>
    <wp:post_date_gmt><![CDATA[2017-12-03 12:03:33]]></wp:post_date_gmt>
    <wp:comment_status><![CDATA[open]]></wp:comment_status>
    <wp:ping_status><![CDATA[closed]]></wp:ping_status>
    <wp:post_name><![CDATA[1]]></wp:post_name>
    <wp:status><![CDATA[inherit]]></wp:status>
    <wp:post_parent>13244</wp:post_parent>
    <wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>
    <wp:post_type><![CDATA[attachment]]></wp:post_type>
    <wp:post_password><![CDATA[]]></wp:post_password>
    <wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>
    <wp:attachment_url><![CDATA[http://www.site.com.kz/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/13244-1.jpg]]></wp:attachment_url>
    <wp:postmeta>
      <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_wp_attached_file]]></wp:meta_key>
      <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[2017/12/13244-1.jpg]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_wp_attachment_metadata]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[a:5:{s:5:"width";i:1000;s:6:"height";i:700;s:4:"file";s:19:"2017/12/13244-1.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:0:{}s:10:"image_meta";a:12:{s:8:"aperture";s:1:"0";s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";s:1:"0";s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";s:1:"0";s:3:"iso";s:1:"0";s:13:"shutter_speed";s:1:"0";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:11:"orientation";s:1:"0";s:8:"keywords";a:0:{}}}]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_wp_attachment_image_alt]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[13245]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
</item>
```

Плагин [WordPress-Importer](https://github.com/humanmade/WordPress-Importer/) не помог.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69674/discussion-on-question-by-------wordpress).

Answer (score 0):

> При стандартном импорте данных с сайта `localhost` на сервер не
>   прикрепляется изображение к галереи `_wp_attached_file`.

И не прикрепятся.  Как сервер поймёт, что `localhost` - это твой локалхост и как получит *с него* картинки? Никак.

Бери [дубликатор](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) и переноси сайт на сервер.  Если нужен непременно импорт, то переноси на временный/тестовый домен, потом делай с него экспорт и уже его импортируй на рабочий домен.

**АПД** после уточнений. Можно попробовать новый, еще тестовый плагин импорта https://github.com/humanmade/WordPress-Importer/
*Но с дубликатом все равно лучше :)*

Comment: Вообще не понятно зачем это делать вначеле на локаллке, а потом экпорт-импорт на рабочий.. И вообще для импорта товара /много данных есть csv и соответствующие плагины. Локалный сайт вообще зло. но что бы ТАК использовать - ещё больше.

Comment: И да, с таким импортом можно легко накосячить. Он для разовых операций. При обновлении нужно быть очень осторожным. Отчасти поэтому лучше использовать плагины экспорта/импорта через csv. И если нужен тестовый сайт - не делать его на локалке, а лучше рядом. на том же хостинге.  Ну или на другом, но лучше на том же.

Comment: @Даниил тут к сож не форум. Общаться и советовать не легко. Это сервис вопрос-ответ. Причём с уклоном в кодинг.

Comment: Я не вижу причин использовать для наполнения сайта локальный сервер и экспорт-импорт. И проблем в этом не вижу. Это если кратко. Для остального - нужно больше информации. а тут это неудобно делать.

Comment: А как бы это сделали вы ? Как вы это видите ?

Comment: Стандартный плагин срабатывает лучше "WordPress import (v2)"